# Unable to bind v-model from v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, petite-vue

I'm having the following setup of vue-petite

form.js

```
import { createApp } from 'https://unpkg.com/petite-vue?module'

const items = [{ title: "Item 1", model: "same_model" }, { title: "Item 2", model: "same_model" }]
const data = { test: "testovaci" }

function Radio() {
    return {
        $template: '#radio-template'
    }
}
const same_model = ""

createApp({
    Radio,
    items,
    data,
    same_model
}).mount();
```

index.html

```
...

<body>
    <script type="module" src="./form.js"></script>
    <div id="formular" v-scope>
        <template id="radio-template" v-for="(item, i) in items">
            <label :for="item.title">{{item.title}}</label>
            <input type="radio" v-model="item.model" :value="item.title" :name="item.title">
        </template>
        <div v-scope="Radio"></div>
        <pre>{{same_model}}</pre>
    </div>
</body>

...
```

I'm unable to bind the `item.model`, I tried also `items[i].model`, when I insert `v-model = "same_model"`, it works.. I went through all the threads here, so this is my last resort actually..

Comment: They do bind, maybe just not the way you want. Putting your code in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/YzRVMNG) with some extra code to view each binding it shows the proper value when you click each radio button.  Because each input has it's own separate v-model, `items[0].model` and `items[1].model` respectively, they don't work together (e.g. toggling one on toggles the other off). If you want them to work together they need the **exact** same v-model, which is why it works when you assign both `same_model`

Comment: hey, thanks, I actually ended up using a data = reactive({same_model:' '}) and binding it to data[items.model] which returned data['same_model'] and ended up working :)

Comment: @RobertHošták you delete your question since it's resolved by you

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev can't I leave it here for anyone else wondering? This is a thing that I spent a lot of time researching without any success.

Comment: @RobertHošták then you should post a well formed answer and accept it so ppl would see the question is succesfuly resolved